# ¿Cómo ver el script de creación de una tabla (CREATE TABLE) en Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

En MySQL, cuando se quiere ver la constitución de una tabla, existe una sentencia SQL que se puede ejecutar como cualquier otra sentencia:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE nombreTabla;
```

Quiero saber si existe una consulta igual para [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql).

He visto que existen sentencias para ejecutar desde la línea de comandos, pero quiero saber si hay una sentencia propiamente SQL que muestre el `CREATE TABLE` de una determinada tabla.

#### El tipo de salida que quisiera

Yo quisiera un tipo de salida en forma de texto, que muestre el script exacto de la creación de la tabla, tal y como lo hace en MySQL, algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE `liturgia` (
  `id_celebracion` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_liturgia` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_tiempo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dia` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `semana` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Mes si es un santo',
  `estatus` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_color` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_celebracion`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_tipo` (`id_tipo`,`id_tiempo`,`dia`,`semana`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=840 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci
```

Comment: Puedes probar con `pg_dump -t 'aschema.atable' --schema-only database-name` [fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2594564/579895)

Comment: Tienes razón @gbianchi, aunque dejé la palabra `CREATE TABLE` en el título, porque la pregunta es específica para Postgresql.

Comment: @Pikoh pues yo creo que incumplo esa norma en todas mis preguntas. Aunque si mal no recuerdo, creo que en meta llegamos a un consenso sobre algunas formas en las que sí era válido usar nombres de etiqueta en el título. No recuerdo ahora el enlace.

Comment: @Pikoh creo que [fue aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2464/29967). Yo me suelo basar en la última sugerencia de Rubén en su respuesta, en la cual cita esto que dice el Centro de Ayuda: ***La única ocasión en la que debes usar etiquetas en tu título es cuando son orgánicos al tono conversacional del título.*** Es así como suelo usarlas.

Comment: Ah perdona que no te comenté nada sobre la solución @Pikoh. Yo busco una solución tipo consulta, o sea, que se pueda ejecutar como una consulta SQL en PgAdmin. Yo había visto soluciones basadas en `pg_dump`, pero son para línea de comandos.

Comment: En ese caso, creo que no existe esa opción, pero no soy experto en postgresql. A ver si alguien mas experto te lo confirma :) [aqui tienes otra referencia](https://serverfault.com/q/231952)

Answer (score 5):

Puedes consultar la tabla `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'nombre_tabla'
```

[Probar sentencia](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5bf0a/66)

[Fuente. SO EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109325/postgresql-describe-table)

---

No he conseguido sacar la `primary key`, aunque con otra select se puede sacar.

Para ver algo parecido al script sería algo así:

```
SELECT                                          
'CREATE TABLE ' || relname || E'\n(\n' ||
array_to_string(
array_agg(
  '    ' || column_name || ' ' ||  type || ' '|| not_null)
, E',\n') || E'\n);\n'
from
(
  SELECT 
  c.relname, a.attname AS column_name,
  pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as type,
  case 
     when a.attnotnull
  then 'NOT NULL' 
  else 'NULL' 
  END as not_null 
FROM pg_class c,
pg_attribute a,
pg_type t
WHERE c.relname = 'company'
AND a.attnum > 0
AND a.attrelid = c.oid
AND a.atttypid = t.oid
ORDER BY a.attnum
) as tabledefinition
group by relname;
```

Lo he sacado de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593803/how-to-generate-the-create-table-sql-statement-for-an-existing-table-in-postgr?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Oh, sí que funciona. Pero una cosa, ¿sabes si hay forma de traerlo como una sola columna, en forma de texto, como ocurre en MySQL?. Resultaría útil por ejemplo si se quiere plantear una pregunta aquí, para incluir cómo se crea la tabla.

Comment: Aún de la segunda forma me saca tres filas en una tabla con tres columnas, una por cada columna. El equivalente en MySQL me da una información completa, exacta de cómo se creó la tabla. Eso es lo que quisiera, como si se tratase de reproducir el `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿Puedes poner en tu pregunta como quieres la salida por favor?

Comment: Editada la pregunta. Cuando ejecuto `SHOW CREATE TABLE tabla` en MySQL me presenta una sola columna con el texto que he puesto al final de la pregunta, yo quisiera obtener un resultado parecido.